# how to add row dynamically in html using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, row

I have a task where I need to add a table row dynamically in HTML where each row has 2 textboxes and the last element is a hyperlink. However, when I add a row the last element hyperlink should be replace by an `<input>` tag. How this can be done? I

I'm able to add a row but I'm unable to change the last element to `<input>` tag, here is my code:

### HTML file

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Add row</title>
<script language=javascript type=text/javascript src="multiplerows.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="CPTbl">
<tr>
<td>
   <input type="text" name="cpName" value="">
</td>
<td>
   <input type="text" name="cpName1" value="">
</td>
<td>
          <a href="samle.htm" View Image</a>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>
<input type="button" value="AddRow" name="AddRowData" onClick="add('CPTbl',1)">
<input type="button" value="Delete Row" name="DeleteAgencyCp" onClick="remove('CPTbl',1);">
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form></body></html>
```

### My script is as below

```
function add(TableId,replicaterow){
    var oMyTable = document.getElementById(TableId);
    var oNewRow;

      if (oMyTable.rows[replicaterow].style.display=="none"){
      if(oMyTable.rows.length==(replicaterow+1)){
          oMyTable.rows[replicaterow].style.display="";
      }else{

        oNewRow = oMyTable.rows[replicaterow].cloneNode(true);
        oNewRow.style.display=""
        ReInitRow(oNewRow,oMyTable.rows.length);
        oMyTable.tBodies[0].appendChild(oNewRow);
      }
      }else{
    oNewRow = oMyTable.rows[replicaterow].cloneNode(true);
    ReInitRow(oNewRow,oMyTable.rows.length);
    oMyTable.tBodies[0].appendChild(oNewRow);
    }       
}

function ReInitRow(oNewRow,rowlength){
  var flg=true;
  if (! oNewRow){return;}
  for (var i = 0 ; i < oNewRow.childNodes.length ; i++){
    if((oNewRow.childNodes[i].tagName == "INPUT") ||
    (oNewRow.childNodes[i].tagName == "SELECT") ||
    (oNewRow.childNodes[i].tagName == "TEXTAREA") ||
    (oNewRow.childNodes[i].tagName == "textarea"))
    {
    oNewRow.childNodes[i].name = oNewRow.childNodes[i].name;
    if((oNewRow.childNodes[i].tagName == "INPUT") &&
        (oNewRow.childNodes[i].type == "text") ||
        (oNewRow.childNodes[i].tagName == "TEXTAREA"))
    {
        oNewRow.childNodes[i].value = "";
    }
    if(oNewRow.childNodes[i].tagName == "SELECT" && !oNewRow.childNodes[i].multiple ){
        oNewRow.childNodes[i].selectedIndex=0;
    }
    if(oNewRow.childNodes[i].id == "resetList")
    {
    oNewRow.childNodes[i].options.length=0;
    }
    if((oNewRow.childNodes[i].type=="hidden")){
        flg=false;
        oNewRow.childNodes[i].value="0";
    }
    }
    ReInitRow(oNewRow.childNodes[i],rowlength);
  }
}
```

How can I replace the third table data (`<a href="samle.htm" View Image</a>`) with `<input type="file" name="photo" value="">`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you explain what isn't working with your current solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a rather blunt way to approach it, but you don't have id's for anything that would help.

```
        ...
        if (!oNewRow) { return; }

        if (oNewRow.tagName == 'TD') {

            var anchors = oNewRow.getElementsByTagName('a');

            if (anchors.length > 0) {
                // found your hyperlink 
                oNewRow.removeChild(anchors[0]); // assuming there's only the one link

                var fi = document.createElement('input');
                fi.type = 'file';
                fi.name = 'photo';
                oNewRow.appendChild(fi);
            }
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < oNewRow.childNodes.length; i++) {
        ...
```

also your code is set up to clone the button row. the row with the inputs and the hyperlink is row 0, not row 1, at least in IE. you might look for a more reliable way of obtaining row references in your code.

Answer (score 0):

@Apache - type in your original HTML code:

```
<a href="samle.htm" View Image</a>
```

Should be:

```
<a href="samle.htm">View Image</a>
```

Comment: this would be more appropriate as a comment than an answer, since it does not address OP's question.

Comment: Yes, it would be great if I was able to add a comment to the OP's question, but I don't have that option yet.